# How can IntelliJ idea 15 using its bundled jdk for font rendering

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts

My local machine JDK version is 18 (Mac OS X 10.11).
In idea14 with bundled JDK,it changed the font-rendering with idea's bundled JDK.It make the font seems more beautiful.

But in idea15, it rollbacked to the past way,using my local machine installed JDK for it's font rendering.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: I solved it by deleting the 'jre' folder in Applications Content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found easy in IDEA 16+.

Double Shift and input
Switch IDE
[image]